# Issue with Invoke of tensorflow endpoint inference via lambda function on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, endpoint

i have trained tensorflow model and deployed it as an endpoint on AWS.

i am trying to use lambda function with api gateway to trigger inference of one instance of data, i am trying to do inference on matrix of 8x8 of data, output should be just single number

i am struggling a lot with the format of request body that is passed to lambda function, i get always Validation error

```
`{"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Body, value: {'instances': [[[0.30050477, 0.31565664, 0.03535339, 0.25252531, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.26515138, 0.32828271, 0.11616141, 0.25757545, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.29292932, 0.45707068, 0.20959599, 0.44696943, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.4242426, 0.44949475, 0.05808071, 0.06565664, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.09595941, 0.44696943, 0.0, 0.36868672, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.33838396, 0.89898997, 0.3055554, 0.85101003, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.84090927, 0.89646466, 0.77272732, 0.85858596, 0.51226546, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.85606065, 0.85606065, 0.76262607, 0.7878787, 0.5910121, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0]]]}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object", "errorType": "ParamValidationError", "requestId": "a1d05ff9-86fb-4a30-9dcb-2651bb001b6c", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 19, in lambda_handler\n    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 691, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 739, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 360, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"]}`
```

my request body as test in aws lambda

```
`{"instances": [[[0.30050477, 0.31565664, 0.03535339, 0.25252531, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236,     0.0], [0.26515138, 0.32828271, 0.11616141, 0.25757545, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.29292932, 0.45707068, 0.20959599, 0.44696943, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.4242426, 0.44949475, 0.05808071, 0.06565664, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.09595941, 0.44696943, 0.0, 0.36868672, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.33838396, 0.89898997, 0.3055554, 0.85101003, 0.37373726, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.84090927, 0.89646466, 0.77272732, 0.85858596, 0.51226546, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0], [0.85606065, 0.85606065, 0.76262607, 0.7878787, 0.5910121, 0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.0]]]}`
```

my lambda function:

```
`ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
payload = data['instances']
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                   ContentType='application/json',
                                   Body=data)
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())

return result`
```

i went through documentation on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-inference.html and tried multiple combination of my json input according documentation but always got validation error

when i trigger endpoint from sagemaker jupyter notebook i use following format

```
`{'instances': array([[[0.30050477, 0.31565664, 0.03535339, 0.25252531, 0.37373726,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ],
     [0.26515138, 0.32828271, 0.11616141, 0.25757545, 0.37373726,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ],
     [0.29292932, 0.45707068, 0.20959599, 0.44696943, 0.37373726,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ],
     [0.4242426 , 0.44949475, 0.05808071, 0.06565664, 0.37373726,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ],
     [0.09595941, 0.44696943, 0.        , 0.36868672, 0.37373726,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ],
     [0.33838396, 0.89898997, 0.3055554 , 0.85101003, 0.37373726,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ],
     [0.84090927, 0.89646466, 0.77272732, 0.85858596, 0.51226546,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ],
     [0.85606065, 0.85606065, 0.76262607, 0.7878787 , 0.5910121 ,
      0.62584169, 0.66940236, 0.        ]]])}`
```

this will output prediction {'predictions': [[0.875023425]]}, however i am not really sure how to pass above input as request body via api gateway.

Would you please help? How am i supposed to fix this validation error?

Filip

Since it is validation error of request body data, i went through documentation and tried multiple variation of body format that is passed in lambda function, did not help, always got the same error over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

so i finally figured it out, the problem was in format of data that were passed in invoke_endpoint in aws lambda function.

i had to use ***json.dumps(event)*** command to get data in proper format, then i was able to pass it to invoke_endpoint method.

```
payload = json.dumps(event)

response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                  ContentType='application/json',
                                  Body=payload)

pred = json.loads(response['Body'].read())

final_prediction = pred["predictions"][0][0]

return final_prediction
```